# Solving differential equation representing an anharmonic oscillator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have been given the following:

Consider an anharmonic oscillator which obeys the differential equation

$$\ddot x(t)=3\Omega^2 x^2(t) -4\Omega^2 x^3(t) \tag{1}$$

We are interested in the solution $x(t)$ subject to the initial condition $x(0)=1$ and $\dot x (0)=0$

1. solve the differential equation within a series expansion $$x(t) = c_0 + c_1 t + c_2 t^2 + c_3 t^3 + c_4 t^4 + \cdots \tag{2}$$ and compute the first five coefficients by direct inspection, or otherwise. You may wish to compute first $x'''(0)$ and $x''''(0)$ from $(1)$, and then compare with $(2)$
2. Show that $$x(t) = \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{2}\Omega^2t^2},$$
   is a solution to $(1)$ in closed form.
3. Confirm that the Taylor expansion of the exact solution agrees with your result

---

I am posting this here as I have absolutely no idea as to where to start. If someone could point me in the right direction that'd be great. Thanks.

Comment: what is $\Omega $ ? Function or constant ?

Comment: I havn't been told, I am assuming it is some constant angular frequency

Answer (score 1):

The Taylor expansion of the solution is
\begin{align}
x(t)&=x(0)+x'(0)\,t+\frac{x''(0)}{2!}\,t^2+\frac{x'''(0)}{2!}\,t^3+\dots\\
&=1+\frac{x''(0)}{2!}\,t^2+\frac{x'''(0)}{2!}\,t^3+\dots
\end{align}
To compute $x''(0)$, observe that from the equation
$$
x''(0)=3\,\Omega^2\, x^2(0) -4\,\Omega^2\, x^3(0)=3\,\Omega^2 -4\,\Omega^2=-\Omega^2.
$$
To compute $x'''(0)$ derivate the equation with respect to $t$:
$$
x'''(t)=6\,\Omega^2\,x(t)\,x'(t)-12\,\Omega^2\,x(t)^2\,x'(t).
$$
Now let $t=0$ and use the initial conditions and the previous computations to get the value of $x'''(0)$.

To get higher values of the derivatives of the solution, keep on taking derivatives.